# Multi Domain SSL for different ip?

Tags: tls, certificates

i have 5 domains`(example.com,example2.net...)` hosted on separate servers. is possible to use one Multi domain SSL certificate for these domain ?

Comment: Sure but why would you want to do that ?

Comment: @Stephane Slightly less management overhead.

Comment: @Stephane Cost effective

Comment: For future reference, SSL certificates are not tied to IP address, per se. They are tied to the CN or Common Name assigned in the certificate. As long as the target host resolves to the CN you're good.

Comment: This is not correct: SSL certificates are neither tied to the common name nor to the IP address. They are usually tied to the hostname which must match the names in the SAN (subject alternative names) section of the certificate or the common name. But you might also tie a certificate to specific IP addresses, which is usually only done if there is no hostname associated with the address.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you can.   You can have all of the domains listed in the SAN (Subject Alternate Name) field in the one certificate, and use it for them all.

This comes with a couple of things to consider, namely:

1. If any of your servers are compromised, or the certificate is leaked, you'll have to replace it everywhere.  You now have approximately five times the risk of the cert being compromised, and if it is, it can be used in attacks against any of the domains.  This is a real risk if one of the domains is particularly sensitive and its servers are hardened, and another is significantly less sensitive and not as much care is taken to protect its servers.   It's less of a risk if all of the domains are roughly equal in size and value, and of your, your mileage may vary.
2. The benefit, on the other hand is that you have slightly less management overhead.  Now you only have one cert to worry about renewing, and one renewal date.  This reduction in overhead may well be worth the bit of additional risk.